# Error when connecting to SQL Server from NodeJS running in Docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I'd like to set up a local web server using NodeJs, SQL Server, React running inside a Docker container.

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file in my root directory:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
sql-server-db:
container_name: sql-server-db
image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
ports:
  - "1433:1433"
environment:
  SA_PASSWORD: "super_duper_password"
  ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
backend:
container_name: backend
build: .
depends_on: [sql-server-db]
ports:
  - "1434:1434"
environment:
  - DATABASE_PUBLIC_URL=sql-server-db
links: 
  - sql-server-db
frontend:
container_name: frontend
image: node:18
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
working_dir: /app/frontend
volumes:
  - ./frontend:/app
command: npm start
```

and the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.11.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When I run `docker compose up` from the root dir I get the following error:

```
/app/node_modules/mssql/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:2438
    for await (const data of message) {
        ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

I have the following `index.js` file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sql = require('mssql');
const app = express();
const port = 3306;

const config = {
  user: 'sa',
  password: 'super_duper_password',
  server: 'localhost',
  database: 'testdb',
  options: {
    enableArithAbort: true,
    encrypt: false,
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    trustedConnection: true,
  }
}

const run = async () => {
  let pool;
  try {
    console.log('Connection opening...')
    pool = await sql.connect(config)
    const { recordset } = await sql.query('select * from users')
    console.log(recordset);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } finally {
    await pool.close()
    console.log('Connection closed.')
  }
}

run();
```

If I comment out my index.js and just leave

```
var sql = require('mssql');
```

I get the error as well.

What is wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: What Javascript language are you targeting? The `await` keyword was introduced in es6.

Comment: Aside... Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VM, so from a networking perspective `localhost` refers to the container itself. Containers in a composition, as you have (unless you're using the default `bridge` network), can refer to each other by their name. Have you tried `server: "sql-server-db"` yet? Failing that, services on the Docker host, or from other containers outside the composition, could be accessed using `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: Aside... `trustedConnection: true` means to use Windows Authentication, as opposed to the SQL Login implied by the `user` and `password` properties that you've also supplied. Windows Authentication can only work from Docker containers if you've gone to the trouble of installing and configuring a Kerberos client in the container.

Comment: I got errors for both:

Failed to connect to sql-server-db:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)

ConnectionError: Failed to connect to host.docker.internal:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host.docker.internal

Comment: Don't include `:1433` in the `server` property. `1433` is the default port, but if you're using a different port number then you can specify it in the `port` property, ref: [mssql # Configuration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#general-same-for-all-drivers).